# ImageMagick number of supported formats: 0

Tags: php, php-7, imagick, php-7.4

Why Imagick supports empty formats?

What should I do?

**my php 7.4.11**

**imagick v : 3.4.4**

**php-imagick.dll v : 7.4.0**

**my os : win10 64x**

[image]

Comment: You are missing ImageMagick, which is required by Imagick